# Adding char to string in C++

Tags: c++, arduino

I work with Eclipse and Arduino.

I want to add a char to a string. I tried to use append,insert ( but these can not be resolved)
I tried to use += but when i print the string it always have one char.Basically i deletes the string and writes only the new char i want to add in.
I tried also concat and it does the same thing.Also strcat gives me headache with the operands cause it needs a const char pointer and i want to add a char that changes.

```
while (theSettings.available()) {

character = theSettings.read();
if(character == '/')         {
    // Comment - ignore this line
    while(character != '\n'){
        character = theSettings.read();
    }
} else if(isalnum(character)){  // Add a character to the description

    Serial.println(character);

    description +=character;
    //description.concat(character);
    Serial.println(description);
}
```

Comment: This is not C but C++.

Comment: What's the type of `description`?

Comment: By the way, this has nothing to do with Eclipse. Your code is faulty, not the IDE. You'd have gotten the exact same error if you used `vi` and `make` or `emacs` instead of Eclipse.

Comment: Yes you are correct,but arduino code is C/C++ so any solution would be great for me

Comment: @kyrpav There is no language called "C/C++". Arduino code is thinly-veiled C++.

Comment: @kyrpav I guess C/C++ it's not only the syntax but also the way you think for your app

Comment: Well arduino ide understand Concat and adds the char but eclipse does not

Comment: description is string

Comment: @kyrpav Neither of them "understands" any of your code. Maybe the Arduino IDE has built-ins for recognizing and certain functions in the Arduino library and highlighting them, but that's all.

Comment: well i think that you could understand that by saying understand this is what i mean.Also eclipse uses arduino core as library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want (for convenience) is the String object class available with the Arduino library.
http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject

Answer (score 1):

If `description` is of the Ardunio-specific [`String`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject) type, you should be able to use the `+=` operator to append.

Comment: i tried but when i print the string i get one char always it just replays it

Answer (score 0):

You can do a very simple thing;

```
Serial.print(character);
Serial.print("");
Serial.println(description);
```

alternatively you can use "dtostrf" if you need to concatenate float and strings